# Is a Java array of primitives stored in stack or heap?

Tags: java, arrays, heap-memory, primitive-types, stack-memory

I have an array declaration like this:

```
int a[];
```

Here `a` is an array of primitive `int` type. Where is this array stored? Is it stored on heap or stack? This is a primitve type `int`, all primitive types are not stored on heap.

Comment: That is not an array. It is a reference to an array. The reference itself could be stored on the heap if it is a member of a class or object, or on the stack if it is a local variable in a method. And primitive types can be stored on the heap if they are members of a class or object.

Answer (score 165):

As gurukulki said, it's stored on the heap. However, your post suggested a misunderstanding probably due to some well-intentioned person propagating the myth that "primitives always live on the stack". This is untrue. *Local variables* have their values on the stack, but not all primitive variables are local...

For example, consider this:

```
public class Foo
{
    int value;
}
...

public void someOtherMethod()
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    ...
}
```

Now, where does `f.value` live? The myth would suggest it's on the stack - but actually it's part of the new `Foo` object, and lives on the heap<sup>1</sup>. (Note that the value of `f` itself is a reference, and lives on the stack.)

From there, it's an easy step to arrays. You can think of an array as just being a lot of variables - so `new int[3]` is a bit like having a class of this form:

```
public class ArrayInt3
{
    public readonly int length = 3;
    public int value0;
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, it's more complicated than this. The stack/heap distinction is mostly an implementation detail - I believe some JVMs, possibly experimental ones, can tell when an object never "escapes" from a method, and may allocate the whole object on the stack. However, it's *conceptually* on the heap, if you choose to care.

Comment: About the "escape analyisis" in Java: http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/12/17/objects-with-no-allocation-overhead/

It says that it is present since the early access release of JDK 6 Update 14, and enabled by default since JDK 6 Update 23.

Comment: does it change anything if array is public static final? Shouldn't it be part of the constant pool then?

Comment: @Malachiasz: Nope. An array is never a constant.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In all versions of the Java library I'm aware of, every `String` is backed by a `char[]`.  I believe literal strings are stored in the public constant pool; for GC optimization, that would imply that the backing arrays should be stored likewise (otherwise the constant pool would have to be scanned during any GC cycle where the backing array would otherwise be eligible for collection).

Comment: @supercat: Yes, that would make sense. But any array you declare *yourself* never ends up as part of the constant pool.

Answer (score 43):

It will be stored on the **heap**

because array is an object in java.

**EDIT**  : if you have

```
int [] testScores; 
testScores = new int[4];
```

Think of this code as saying to the compiler, "Create an array object that will hold four ints, and assign it to the reference variable named `testScores`. Also, go ahead and set each `int` element to zero. Thanks."

Comment: And the reference variable named testScores(pointing to the array on the heap) will be on the stack.

Comment: The code only says "Thanks" if you supply the `-g` option to the compiler. Otherwise it will be optimized away.

Comment: @mob You are making an assumption that this is the only code. It is probably better to assume that these two lines are part of a larger program which actually uses the array.

Answer (score 27):

It is an array of primitive types which in itself is not primitive. A good rule of thumb is when the new keyword is involved the result will be on the heap.

Answer (score 23):

I just wanted to share few tests I ran on this subject.

Array of size 10 million

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    memInfo();
    double a[] = new double[10000000];
    memInfo();
}
```

Output:

```
------------------------
max mem = 130.0 MB
total mem = 85.0 MB
free mem = 83.6 MB
used mem = 1.4 MB
------------------------
------------------------
max mem = 130.0 MB
total mem = 130.0 MB
free mem = 48.9 MB
used mem = 81.1 MB
------------------------
```

As you see used heap size is increased by ~80 MB, which is 10m * sizeof(double).

But if we have use Double instead of double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    memInfo();
    Double a[] = new Double[10000000];
    memInfo();
}
```

Output will show 40MB. We only have Double references, they are not initialized.

Filling it with Double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    memInfo();
    Double a[] = new Double[10000000];      
    Double qq = 3.1d;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = qq;
    }
    memInfo();
}
```

Still 40MB. Because they all point to same Double object.

Initializing with double instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    memInfo();
    Double a[] = new Double[10000000];
    Double qq = 3.1d;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = qq.doubleValue();
    }
    memInfo();
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Line

```
a[i] = qq.doubleValue();
```

is equivalent to

```
a[i] = Double.valueOf(qq.doubleValue());
```

which is equivalent to

```
a[i] = new Double(qq.doubleValue());
```

Since we create new Double objects each time, we blow out the heap.
This shows values inside the Double class are stored in heap.

Comment: Could you paste the code detail of memInfo() pls? :)

Answer (score 3):

In the Java programming language arrays are objects, are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two ways of looking at it, when we do something like this

```
    int arr[] = new int[4];
    for( int i=0;i<=3;i++ ){
        arr[i] = i*10;
    }
```

than I think  the array is stored in heap and only the reference ariable "arr" is stored in stack.
But when we do something like this `int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50};` then everything is stored in stack

Comment: @ManOffSky now this answer got very *strange*....

Comment: @ManOffSky Your edit makes no sense as an edit. It should have been rejected and written as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the example int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50};, both the array itself and its values will be stored in the heap, while the reference variable arr will be stored in the stack.