# Arrays in Java and how they are stored in memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I'm trying to understand the array setup in java. Why must you initialize space for each each object in the array, after you have created the array. How is it stored in memory like this:

```
[object][object]
```

or like this:

```
[*class]->[object]  
[*class]->[object]
```

In other words, what is actually being done in memory.  Does `array[0] = new class()` just return a reference to a reserved location in memory, and the `class[] array = new class[10]` statement create something along the lines of 10 pointers, which are later assigned to by the new statements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Array is stored in stack or heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099695/java-array-is-stored-in-stack-or-heap)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Arrays in Java store one of two things: either primitive values (`int`, `char`, ...) or references (a.k.a pointers).

So, `new Integer[10]` creates space for 10 `Integer` references only. It does **not** create 10 `Integer` objects (or even free space for 10 `Integer` objects).

Incidentally that's exactly the same way that fields, variables and method/constructor parameters work: they too only store primitive values or references.

Comment: Is there a difference in memory between the way arrays of primitives are stored than arrays of objects

Comment: Since there are no references to primitive values, the values themselves are stored in the array instead of references.

Comment: What about the length?  Arrays in Java know their length.  Isn't that stored somewhere?  Or is that a compile-time-only thing?

Answer (score 7):

If you are familiar with C/C++ **you can think of Java object references as pointers to objects** (or pointers to structs). So:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Helios");
```

is:

- declare a p pointer to a Person struct (in the stack)
- reserve memory for and initialize Person struct
- assign its address to p
- execute method setName on object referenced by p

So when you are doing:

```
Person[] ps = new Person[5];
```

**you are reserving an array of 5 references to Person**. Next you will have to create each real person and assign each reference to a place in the array.

**Edit:** the (almost) C/C++ version of the previous code

```
class Person { ... };
typedef PersonStruct* Person; // I don't remember if this declaration is ok
Person p = new PersonStruct();
p -> setName(...);

Person[] ps = new Person[5]; 
// ps is a variable in the stack pointing to the array in the heap
// (being the array five references to the PersoStruct)
```

and you could do

```
ps[3] = p;
```

Comment: So it is almost as if you are creating a person *p[] array then assigning one by one to p[0] throughout p[length-1]?

Comment: Yes. It's like this. In my example code ps is the array. It's also a reference (located in the stack) to the array structure (located in the heap). The array structure is the one who will hold the references to the five Person objects. I'll add a C/C++ translation :)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are continuous space of memory, so they look like more your first sketch:

`[object-reference][object-reference]`

`array[0] = new class()` will store in `array[0]` a reference to the new created object.

`class[] array = new class[10]` will create an array of ten empty slots (or ten null references).

Comment: Actually it's similar to the second example in the OP's question.