# Return a bubble sort as a separate array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, arrayobject

I'm trying to write a program that generates an array populated by random numbers, then bubble sorts them and returns the sorted array as a separate array so you can compare the two.

However, once I create my random array and then try to created another sorted one, the sorted array "overwrites" the random one and the random one appears as a sorted one when I try to print it out.

My question is: How can I modify my code so that I can create and array of random doubles, then generate another, separate, array which is the sorted version of that random one?

Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BubbleMain {

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    int n;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
            n = keyboard.nextInt();

            if(n >= 2){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Size must be 2 or greater");
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Value must be an integer");
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }


    double[] template = new double[n];
    double[] mess = Bubble.randPop(template);

    double[] tidy = Bubble.bubbleSort(mess);


    Bubble.printOut(mess);
    Bubble.printOut(tidy);


}
}
```

Bubble Class:

```
public class Bubble {

private double[] list;

public Bubble(double[] list){

    this.list = list;
}

public double[] getArray(){
    return list;
}

public static double[] randPop(double[] template){

    for(int i = 0; i < template.length; i++){
        template[i] = Math.random();
    }

    return template;
}



public static double[] bubbleSort(double[] mess){

    double[] tidy = new double[mess.length];

    for(int i=0; i<mess.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i + 1; j<mess.length; j++)
        {
            if(mess[i] > mess[j])
            {
                double temp = mess[i];
                mess[i] = mess[j];
                mess[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        tidy[i] = mess[i];
    }
    return tidy;
}




public static void printOut(double[] list){

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Clone the array, then sort either the original or the clone.

Comment: You are sorting the original array and then copying it to the new array which gives you two sorted arrays. You need to copy the array first, and then sort one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are arrays passed by value or passed by reference in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java)

Comment: You are incorrectly assuming that the array is copied when passed to the `bubbleSort` method. This is wrong. For the details of wkhat Java does, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a copy of the array first:

```
public static double[] bubbleSort(double[] mess){
    // Copy the array    
    double[] tidy = Arrays.copyOf(mess, mess.length);

    // sort
    for(int i=0; i<tidy.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i + 1; j<tidy.length; j++)
        {
            if(tidy[i] > tidy[j])
            {
                double temp = tidy[i];
                tidy[i] = tidy[j];
                tidy[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return tidy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bubbleSort`, you are sorting the `mess` array and then assigning it to `tidy`. So mess will be sorted, and tidy will also refer to the sorted array.

You need to [copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) the array to `tidy`

```
double[] tidy = Arrays.copyOf(mess, mess.length);
```

and then sort.