# Value of the array "r" gets updated to 2?

Tags: java, arrays, static, static-methods

"Why does the value of r change to 2 2 while it's re that I am changing, that too in another function?"

```
class Ideone {// main
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int[] r = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            System.out.println(r[i]);
        int[] catch1 = doesThisWork(1, 2, r);
        // the value of r changes!?
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            System.out.println(r[i]);
    }// doesthisWork

    public static int[] doesThisWork(int a, int b, int[] re) {
        for (int i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
            re[i] = b;
        }
        return re;
    }
}
```

Comment: This link might help you understand why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java

Comment: have a look at (objects are passed by reference in java ) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 3):

`doesThisWork` accepts a reference to the `r` array, which means it is able to change the contents of that array. While assigning a new value to the `re` variable inside the method wouldn't change the value of `r` when the method returns (since Java is a pass by value language), changing the state of the object referred by `re` (which is an array in your case), affects the state of `r`, since `r` and `re` refer to the same object.

Answer (score 3):

**Java is pass by value of the reference!**

So when you do

```
public static int[] doesThisWork(int a, int b, int[] re) {
    for (int i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
        re[i] = b;
    }
    return re;
}
```

your `int[] re` is referring to actual array instance pointed by `int[] r` and any change made will be reflected to original array.

Answer (score 0):

in this code when give `int[] r` as an entry to `doesThisWork(int a, int b, int[] re)`, be careful because java hold the pointer to r and if any changes happen to re It means the pointer also has to change the reference  (it is *call by reference*).
in order to solve this problem use a tmp array:

```
    int[] tmp = re
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        tmp[i] = b;
    }
    return tmp;
```