# how does this work? - Java code

Tags: java

So I've got this piece of code,

```
package test1;
class Student13
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        Student13 p = new Student13();
        p.start();
    }

    void start() 
    {
        long [] a1 = {3,4,5};
        long [] a2 = fix(a1);
        System.out.print(a1[0] + a1[1] + a1[2] + " ");
        System.out.println(a2[0] + a2[1] + a2[2]);
    }

    long [] fix(long [] a3) 
    {
        a3[1] = 7;
        return a3;
    } 
}
```

Can you tell me why it returns `15 15` and not `12 15`? Function `fix` is applied only for `long[] a2`, so how come that the final result is `15 15`?

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the issue.

Comment: Arrays are [passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12757853/3773066), so the changes will persist.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the a1 array to `fix()`, which is called `a3` in the `fix()` method, but is regardless still referencing `a1`. So when you update `a3`: `a3[1]=7`, you actually update the paramater value of `fix()` which was `a1`. Thus you updated `a1`!

Comment: Thanks! So if i'd put the fix function after the first println the final result would be 12 and 15, right?

Comment: If you'd put: `long[] a2 = fix(new long[]{3,4,5});` your output will be 12 15.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
long a1[] = { ... };
```

you are creating one array object. This will be the only one throughout the rest of the program.

Now the call to

```
fix(a1);
```

assigns a reference to exactly that array to the parameter `a3` in this `fix` method. As this method returns this reference (`return a3;`), the line

```
long[] a2 = fix(a1);
```

will assign the same reference to the variable `a2`. So at all points, all variables and parameters referred to the same array.

The `fix` method is modifying that array. So the modification is *seen* by all aliases you have.

Answer (score 0):

Reference of `a1[]` is passed as a parameter to `fix()` that's why basically

`a1[] == a2[]` after calling `fix()`.

`a2[]` is pointing to `a1[]` but `a1[]` sum is now 15, so `a2[]` sum is also 15.