# replace array item, source value is replaced too on public static void

Tags: java

After I replace the index 0 of an array in the function, the value of `arrayCharacter` is also changed. The result is

```
[A, B, C] [ko, B, C] [ko, B, C]
```

I don't understand why the result is not:

```
[A, B, C] [A, B, C] [A, B, C]
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayCharacter = new String[]{"A", "B", "C"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            proses(arrayCharacter);
        }
    }

    public static void proses(String[] arrayCharacter) {
        String[] characterTemp = arrayCharacter;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayCharacter));
        characterTemp[0] = "ko";
    }
}
```

Comment: See: [Are arrays passed by value or passed by reference in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in this line: `String[] characterTemp = arrayCharacter;` you are not copying the array, but rather you have `characterTemp` and `arrayCharacter` pointing at the same memory location. Thus, any changes done to one will be reflected to the other.

The solution is to copy the content of the source array. [`System.arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) does that for you:

```
public static void proses(String[] arrayCharacter) {
        String[] characterTemp = new String[arrayCharacter.length];
        System.arrayCopy(arrayCharacter, 0, characterTemp, 0, characterTemp.length); //This will create a separate copy of the array.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayCharacter));
        characterTemp[0] = "ko";
    }
```