# Why is variable being modified from a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, scope

### Background

I am making an array tools class for adding Python functionality to a Java array, and I came across this problem. This is obviously a simplified, more universal version.

### Question

In this example:

```
public class ArrayTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // initial setup
        int[] given = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        // change array
        int[] changed = adjust(given);

        // these end up being the same...
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(changed));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(given));
    }
    private static int[] adjust(int[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i]++;
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

...why is `changed` and `given` the same thing?

### Disclaimer

I am guessing that this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer, so I apologize for that.

Comment: You're right that this must be a duplicate. Searching for it is tricky, but we should be able to find one.

Comment: modifying the array passed into a method will modify that array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
int[] given = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

`given`'s value is called an *object reference*. It's a value telling the JVM where that array is, elsewhere in memory. `given` doesn't *contain* the array (like it would an `int`), it contains a *reference* to the array (e.g., like an address). E.g.:

```
                     +−−−−−−−−−+
[given:Ref88465]−−−−>| (array) |
                     +−−−−−−−−−+
                     | 0: 1    |
                     | 1: 2    |
                     | 2: 3    |
                     | 3: 4    |
                     | 4: 5    |
                     +−−−−−−−−−+
```

When you call `adjust(given)`, you're passing a copy of the value of `given` into `adjust`. That copy still points to the same place in memory. E.g., *during* the call to `adjust`, we have two copies of that object reference, both pointing to the same single array:

```
                     +−−−−−−−−−+
[given:Ref88465]−−−−>| (array) |
                  /  +−−−−−−−−−+
                  |  | 0: 1    |
                  |  | 1: 2    |
                  |  | 2: 3    |
                  |  | 3: 4    |
                  |  | 4: 5    |
                  |  +−−−−−−−−−+
[a:Ref88465]−−−−−−+
```

When you change the contents of the array, you're modifying the state of array. When `adjust` returns and you assign the result to `changed`, you have:

```
                      +−−−−−−−−−+
[given:Ref88465]−−−−−>| (array) |
                   /  +−−−−−−−−−+
                   |  | 0: 2    |
                   |  | 1: 3    |
                   |  | 2: 4    |
                   |  | 3: 5    |
                   |  | 4: 6    |
                   |  +−−−−−−−−−+
[changed:Ref88465]−+
```

If you want a *copy* of the array with the changes, you'll need to make a copy of it, for instance via `arraycopy`. Both copying and changing-in-place are used in practice, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is sending the address of your array to your method , so what was changed is your original array  and you just return it( the address of your array) so any change you have done on that array(memory) will be reflected in both variables as both are pointing to the same memory location

Comment: In Java we are not talking about _address_ but about _reference_.

Comment: Not really , references are misunderstood, they are more like pointers actually

Comment: And what i meant(sorry if that was not clear) is just address more like a proxy not a physical address of the memory

Comment: Oh oh. No! It is _reference_! Please stick to the correct terms.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa reference variables hold values which allow JVM map that value to proper object location. Objects can be moved inside memory by JMV so their address may change, but that doesn't mean reference will also change.

Comment: you are not sending the reference

Comment: You are sending the copy of a reference. Pointers can change the address they point to, which in Java is prohibited.

Comment: @Pshemo ,@MaxZoom I agree with both of you , this copy of the reference is basically the address to that reserved memory in the heap , not the physical memory i mean a proxy to that location , about using "copy of reference" i do not see thats accurate maybe better to say "value of reference" ?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa: It's a copy of the value, just like `int a = 42; int b = a;` copies the value of `a` (42) into `b`. The value in that case is an `int`; in the OP's case it's an object reference, but it's a value either way. So "copy of the reference" is entirely correct.

Comment: Well guess thats correct.