# Value changes but is only used as parameter

Tags: java, php, arrays, algorithm

I have to re write my implementation vor insert/selection-sort in Java from PHP. So, the algorithms work fine but as it's a pain in the rear to work with all the different types when writing a quick programm I'm using a Logger Class in order to save my multi-type values.

As I haven't worked with Java for a while, there might be a problem in the code that causes this weird bug.

I have to iterate over an Integer Array in order to generate and sort random Arrays of different lengths:

```
 public static Log[][] eval(Integer[] sizes, Algorithm alg){

        Log[][] logs = new Log[sizes.length][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            Log[] tmp = new Log[3];
            Integer[] rand = randomArray(sizes[i]);
            System.out.println("Before "+Arrays.toString(rand));
            tmp[0] = new Log(sizes[i], rand);
            tmp[1] = alg.insertionSort(rand);
            tmp[2] = alg.selectionSort(rand);
            System.out.println("After "+Arrays.toString(rand));
            logs[i] = tmp;
        }
        return logs;
    }
```

As you see, there are 2 debugs, which will give something like this:

> Before [2, 1, 4, 5, 3]
>
> After [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> Before [1, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 2, 6, 7, 3]
>
> After [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>
> Before [11, 15, 20, 16, 18, 8, 4, 13, 2, 19, 12, 3, 10, 5, 17, 14, 1,
>   9, 6, 7]
>
> After [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
>   19, 20]

This is strange, as I doesnt change the rand value. Even if I put an Int array called backup outside the loop and overwrite it and print out this in the last log, it's still a sorted array. I'm trying to fix this for over a hour and I can't find the bug. It must be within the algorithm methodes for index 1/2, because Before == After when skipping these lines. But I have no clue, what's wrong, as I'm only using the array as parameter and return an Object of Log.

Here's one algorithm-method:

```
public Log insertionSort(Integer[] sortieren) {
    double startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < sortieren.length; i++) {
        temp = sortieren[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && sortieren[j - 1] > temp) {
            sortieren[j] = sortieren[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        sortieren[j] = temp;
    }
    double stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    double time = stopTime - startTime;
    Log log = new Log("Insertion-Sort", (time/1000000), sortieren);
    return log;
}
```

And this is my Log Class:

```
public class Log {

    public String name;
    public double time;
    public int size;
    public Integer[] sorted;
    public Integer[] randArray;

    public Log(String name, double time, Integer[] sorted){

        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.sorted = sorted;
    }

    public Log(int size, Integer[] random){
        this.size = size;
        this.randArray = random;
    }
}
```

Later, I want to evalue this through this method:

```
 public static void reportLogger(Log[][] log, boolean showArray){

        for (int i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
          // Show Initial Array (0th Index) -> (size, array)
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2 ; j++) {
                Log tmp = log[i][j];
                // 1st/2nd Index -> Insert/Selection ->  name, time, sortedArray by using tmp.name ,etc..
            System.out.println("---------------------");*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is an input parameter, but it is also modified in the first sorting method `alg.insertionSort(rand)`. At this point, the array became a sorted array - no longer a random one. At the point `alg.selectionSort(rand)`, all it's trying to do is sorting on a sorted array `rand`. In order to compare the performance, you should make a copy of the array `rand`:

```
tmp[0] = new Log(sizes[i], rand);
Integer[] array_copy_1 = Array.copyof(rand, rand.size)
tmp[1] = alg.insertionSort(array_copy_1);
Integer[] array_copy_2 = Array.copyof(rand, rand.size)
tmp[2] = alg.selectionSort(array_copy_2);
```

Comment: Okay, but isn't that weird?  I never encountered such a behaviour in the last 2 years. However, thank you  :D Now I'm getting weird NullPointers..dang, I hate Java

Comment: I think it's a problem of pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference of array, you can find a useful answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12757868/2507225).

Comment: Agreed, primitive types are pass-by-value (they are copied) while Objects are not, only the reference is copied, so the object will still be modified if you change it.