# Does the array instance variable not relate to the setter method intake?

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter, setter, instance-variables

> In the main method I make a new object of the DotComClass and set
>   locationOfShips array to 14 numbers. Then send those values as an
>   argument over to the setter method (setLocations) in the other class
>   (see below). My question is why does it allow that pass over without
>   issue, since I set the max number of elements of the locations
>   instance variable is 5?

```
  import java.util.Arrays;

  public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      DotComClass dotCom = new DotComClass();
      int[] locationOfShips = {6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5};        
      dotCom.setLocations(locationOfShips);       
    }
  }

  public class DotComClass {
   int [] locations = new int[5]; // is this not related to the locations in the setter?

   public void setLocations (int[] locations){
     this.locations= locations;
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(locations));
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `locations` field is a *reference* to an array.

This points that reference to a new array of 5 integers.

```
int [] locations = new int[5]; // is this not related to the locations in the setter?
```

This re-points that reference to a *different* array.

```
this.locations= locations;
```

The new array has its own size. It's not limited by the size of the array that the reference formerly pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple mistake you are making, the variable `int [] locations = new int[5];` does not actually contain an array of length 5. It is actually just holding the reference to the array of length 5 somewhere on the heap.

This is exactly what this statement below is also doing,

`int[] locationOfShips = {6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5};`

so when you are running `this.locations= locations;`, you are actually saying the variable now refers to the array `locationOfShips`

If this is not clear i suggest you read about pass by reference good explanation here ([Are arrays passed by value or passed by reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java))