# array staying sorted after first pass not sure why

Tags: java, arrays

As you can tell by my title I wasn't quite sure how to word this. I'm just getting back into some coding and doing basic practice. I thought starting back with sorting algorithms would be great. I'm trying to load a file, then sort it. I have 3 algorithms coded so far. Hopefully I post enough to give you guys an idea of the problem.

My sorting class is changing my array even though I'm trying to update a different array.

I start by loading my array from a file with a function I made called `ReadFileToArray` – which works fine.

```java
int[] arr;
int[] sortedArray;
String fp = "C:/Users/test.txt";
arr = ReadFileToArray(fp);
```

I then using my sorting class to sort the array:

```java
Sorting mySorting = new Sorting();
int SelectionSort = 1
System.out.println("\r\nSorting using selection sort:");
sortedArray = mySorting.SortIt(arr, SelectionSort);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
}
```

This works and sorts fine for the 3 sorting types if have.

The problem though, is if I do another pass for sorting now `arr` is sorted even though it should still maintain the unsorted list (or at least I thought that because I'm updating `sortedArray` with the function, not `arr` itself).

For testing purposes, if I do:

```java
Sorting mySorting = new Sorting();
int SelectionSort = 1
System.out.println("\r\nSorting using selection sort:");
sortedArray = mySorting.SortIt(arr, SelectionSort);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

`arr` now prints sorted as well.

I don't purposely use any pointers or memory stuff so I can't remember why this happens and I can't remember what to Google. I've found I can copy the array to an unsorted array first then just copy it back each time I want to test a sorting algorithm but I was hoping someone could just point me in the right direction for what causes this again.

Thanks!

[Edited to remove file path info.]

Comment: May I suggest editing the question to show a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Off-topic: You can print an entire array using the [`Arrays.toString` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)). That links to the API method taking an `int`, but it is overloaded for other types.

Comment: This question might or might not have answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: By chance, does the `MySort#sortIt (int [] array, int sortType)` method manipulate the contents of the `array` parameter, whatever the actual name is in your source code?  Even though `array` is the name of a local variable within the method, it is a reference type. If this method changes the values in the elements, the change will be made to the  actual array in the calling program.

Comment: I sure hope your Sorting class creates a copy of the input array instead of operating on it directly

Comment: see also Java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/16034206

Comment: I think you need to post the code of class `Sorting`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Dno how to quote here but the link to pass by Val vs by reference with complex data structures really nailed it home.  Good to know this is a java thing not something I'm fundamentally doing wrong. Edit: I'd post more complete code but the question was pretty well answered now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting code modifies (i.e. ruins) the input.

Java is pass-by-value (i.e., a copy is passed whenever you pass a value to a method), but, everything is a reference. When you write:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

The `new int[10]` is akin to 'build a house', but `int[] arr` isn't a house - no, that's just a page in an address book. `=` doesn't mean 'arr is now a house', no, `=` means: write the address of the thing on the right onto the address book page on the left.

So, when you call `SortIt(arr)`, java duly makes a **copy**, but it's copying the address book page. Not the entire house.

Your sort method then follows the copy it got, tosses a brick through the window and speeds off, the little delinquent. Your main method then later goes and follows its address book page to.. the same house, and notices it has been vandalized.

You have 4 options to fix this:

1. Have your main code make a copy, and hand the copy to your sort method. A copy can be made with `Arrays.copyOf(arr)`.
2. Have your sorting method make a copy of whatever error it receives.
3. Having your sorting method do its job without modifying the input. That's.. pretty much going to boil down to option 2, unless the input is already sorted.
4. Write your main code so that it no longer matters that the method you pass the array to modifies it.

Comment: thank you for the run down, makes sense! :) right now i was using Array.copyOf before calling SortIt(arr). is this how you would normally deal with passing arrays thru methods?