# Memory Allocation for Object Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, memory

In my computer science course, we were taught that when you create an array, the JVM will allocate the memory automatically depending on the size of the array. For example if you create an integer array with a size of 10, the JVM would allocate 10 * 32 Bits of data to that array.

My question is, how exactly does this process work when you create arrays of object that have varying sizes? For example a String object. When you create an array of 10 Strings, is any memory actually reserved on the system for these strings, or since they are just pointers, memory allocation isn't necessary?

Comment: You actually build a pointer array, that's correct. So you need the sizeof(pointer) * array_size. Instancing a object you gonna link to an array index takes care about the actual memory allocation of the object.

Comment: This question pretty much answers yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564423/arrays-in-java-and-how-they-are-stored-in-memory

Comment: Actually, in Java, there is only one type of object that has a variable size: array. Everything else has a predetermined size (String holds an array internally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `String` is a class which extends the `Object` class, and objects in Java are passed (and stored in variables) by reference, the array of strings is an array of references to `String` objects. So, when you do

```
String[] a = new String[10];
```

you're creating an array of references, where the size of every reference (not the object it's pointing to) is already known (32 bits for 32-bit machines, and 64 bits for 64 bits machines).

**Upd:** as Jon Skeet said [in one of his answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981130/885028) the size of an actual reference *may be* the same as a native pointer size, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

`int[]` => array of ints

`String []` => array of pointers to String instances

`int[][]` => array of pointers to (separate, disparate) int[] arrays

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are itself an object in Java so it will be always created in runtime. [From Official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> One way to create an array is with the new operator. The next
>   statement in the ArrayDemo program allocates an array with enough
>   memory for 10 integer elements and assigns the array to the anArray
>   variable.
>
> // create an array of integers
>
> anArray = new int[10];
>
> If this
>   statement is missing, then the compiler prints an error like the
>   following, and compilation fails:
>
> ArrayDemo.java:4: Variable anArray may not have been initialized.

Also another [answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564423/arrays-in-java-and-how-they-are-stored-in-memory).