# How much memory allocates to element in Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

Consider the below case

```
int[] anArray = new int[10];
```

Allocates memory for 10 elements of each **32-bit** on heap.Right ?

So what is the size of the  element if the element type is Object. ??

like

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[10];
```

How much memory allocated now on heap ?  I just got the doubt by ssing the source code of `ArrayList`.

```
  private transient Object[] elementData;
```

Just tried this line in my machine

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

results

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.nextenders.server.guice.actions.servlets.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

So I'm trying to know how much memory allocated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays in Java and how they are stored in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564423/arrays-in-java-and-how-they-are-stored-in-memory). See also [How big is an object reference in Java and precisely what information does it contain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-co)

Comment: Allow me to extract (and slightly adjust) the relevant snippets from @Duncan linked questions: `New Object[10] creates space for 10 Object references only. It does not create 10 Object objects (or even free space for 10 Object objects)` and `Each reference will be an address: 32 bit on 32 bit CPU, 64 at 64`

Comment: Yes , see the line `or even free space for 10 Integer objects`. So why `OutOfMemoryError` occurred just for initialization ??

Comment: Because `ArrayList<String>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` requested 2^(31-1) number of addresses.

Comment: strange case I am curious of the solution

Comment: Also, I hope you do realize that arrays are not in fact infinite.

Comment: Google can answer your question easily.

Answer (score 4):

> So what is the size of the element if the element type is Object. ??

The size of an `Object[]` array element is the size of a reference.

- On a 32 bit JVM, a reference is 32 bits (4 bytes)
- On a 64 bit JVM, a reference is 64 bits (8 bytes), or 32 bits if the "compressed oop" optimization is enabled and the heap size is less than 32Gb.

So your array allocation will allocate a heap object containing roughly 4 x 10 or 8 x 10 bytes ... plus about 12 bytes of object header overhead.

> Just tried this line in my machine

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Under the covers, you are attempting to allocate attempting to allocate an array containing between 2<sup>33</sup> and 2<sup>34</sup> bytes.  With a 32bit JVM, that is guaranteed to not work.  With a 64 bit JVM, you'd need a heap of at least 8Gb (compressed oop) or 16Gb for that to work.

Comment: Quote from Oracle: `indicates that the application [...] attempted to allocate an array that is larger than the heap size`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I see.

Comment: @StephenC *12 bytes of object header overhead*, 16 bytes due to memory alignment.

Comment: @Eugene - that depends on the JVM implementation.  That's why I said **about** 12 bytes.

Comment: @StephenC indeed. On JVM 7 update 51, it is 16 bytes, just tested it out. Actually due to this memory alignment we can use compressed oop, as the last 3 bits are always free.

Answer (score 0):

1. 10 x 4bytes = 40 bytes
2. The maximum size for the object store is 256 MB of compressible,
   nonvolatile, RAM storage. The size of the object store can be
   changed to customize the amount of persistent storage available for
   applications and their related data. default Object = 4bytes in
   x32bit and 8bytes in x64bit
3. It is depend on what items of object are holding. Since you are
   not assign any items in object so the Heap will be calculate by
   default Object = 4bytes x 10 = 40bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It will create an array of 10 32 bit references to objects (the memory address where the object is stored) as all objects in java are just pointers to the memory where the object is stored. Or if you are using a 64 bit machine the addresses will be 64 bits