# Why int[] a = new int[1] instead of just int a?

Tags: java, integer

Is there some hidden meaning in this code which I don't see in java? How can it be useful?

```
int[] a = new int[1];
```

than just

```
int a;
```

because from my point of view it's the same?

Comment: The first is an array containing one `int`. The other is just an `int`. Could you explain why you think they're the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int a
```

defines a primitive int.

```
int[] a = new int[1];
```

defines an array that has space to hold 1 int.

They are two very different things. The primitive has no methods/properites on it, but an array has properties on it (length), and methods (specifically its on clone method, and all the methods of Object).

Arrays are a bit of a weird beast.  They are defined in the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.4.5).

In practice, it would make sense to do this when you need to interact with an API that takes an array and operates on the results.  It is perfectly valid to pass in a reference to an array with 0, 1, or n properties.  There are probably other valid reasons to define an array with 1 element.

I can't think of any use cases where you would want to define an array with one element, just to bypass the array and get the element.

Comment: so what's the reason of creating an array of 1 element instead of creating just an int?

Comment: When you have a Java object integer, you have methods you can use to do manipulations on this object. A primitive type only allows basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: From a scope that can access `a` but not reassign it, then the `int[]` allows mutation of the actual `int` value.

Comment: @hvgotcodes +1 .just want to ask ,sometimes i use ArrayName.length without () thus it signifies that length is a static member .But where it is present i.e in which class is it Object.

Comment: myArray.length is NOT a static member.  Any array that you create will have its own length field.  Everything in java that is not a primitive is an Object.  I think array is a special case -- there is no class Array in the Java api.  it is defined in the JLS http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.4.525

Comment: Apart from the ability to pass it in as an array, are there any benefits to using it rather than Integer? (the class, not the primitive int.)

Comment: Are there benefits to using a lawnmower rather than a frying pan?  They are different things and do different things.

Comment: Another use-case of a one-element array is to let an anonymous nested class modify the enclosing scope's local variable values.

Answer (score 7):

One is on the stack, one is on the heap.

Comment: @Algorithmist: Thank you. :-)
@Gabe: Isn't it?

Comment: More explanation on primitive living on stack of heap can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099695/java-array-is-stored-in-stack-or-heap

Answer (score 4):

One difference is that you can write a method that changes its int argument by changing `arg[0]`. This trick is used quite a bit in some of the code I've seen. It allows you to, for instance, return a `boolean` indicate success or failure and an `int` value that serves some other purpose. Without that trick, you'd have to return some sort of object containing the two values.

Comment: Yes, this is a form of pass-by-reference.

Comment: @Gabe - exactly. I guess I could have used one (well, three) words instead of three sentences. :)

Comment: @Gabe - technically speaking, it is a way to **simulate** pass by reference semantics in Java.

Comment: @Stephen: What's the difference between "a form of" and "a way to simulate"?

Comment: @Gabe - one is real, and the other is fake.  In real call-by-reference the callee is passed the address of a variable, either explicitly or implicitly.  In this fake version, the caller has to create and populate an array, and then pull the value out of the array on return.

Comment: Actually, in Java, all objects are passed by reference and all primitives are passed by value. The trick here is passing a primitive by reference by embedding it in an object. An int array in Java is, it turns out, a very convenient object for this. (You might think Integer would be good for that, but Integer is immutable, unlike an int array.)

Comment: This is a common trick, but when I see this nowadays I change the code to use `AtomicBoolean` instead of `boolean[1]`, `AtomicReference<T>` instead of `T[1]`, etc.

Comment: @HuguesM. - Yes, that works very nicely as well. Any mutable object that encapsulates the argument value will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
int a;
```

defines a variable that can hold an int

```
int[] a;
```

defines a variable that can hold an array of int

```
int[] a = new int[1];
```

does that above but also initializes it by actually creating an array (of size 1 - it can hold 1 int) and defines the variable `a` to hold that array, but doesn't define what's in the array.

```
int[] a = new int[1]{1};
```

does that above but also defines what's in the array: the int 1.

I suppose it does a *similar* thing, in that space is allocated for 1 int, but the array also defines an array. I suppose you could say these are similar:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a + 1;
// now b == 2

int[] a = new int[1]{1};
int b = a[0] + 1;   
// now b == 2
```

Comment: Actually, I think that `int[] a = new int[1]{1};` is usually written `int[] a = {1};`

Answer (score 1):

An array of size one is not the same thing as a single integer.

Even if they carry the same information, they are different types, so you can use them in different contexts.

For example, if you have a function which performs a function on all elements of an array but you want to compute it only on one value, you should pass a int[1], because the function expects an array and wants to know how many values it should process.

Answer (score 0):

All arrays in java are objects. when declaring: `int x = 5;` you're declaring a primitive type.

When declaring `int[] x = new int[];` you're creating an object with type `int[]`.

So `int[]` is actually a class.