# Java array initialization second variable type

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
```

Hey guys,
I know there are other ways to initialize an array like:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

But can you tell me what the second `int` in the top example stands for?
I think the first "int" already specifies the array to have integer values, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it specifies that the values are ints but not how many values are allows

Comment: defines an array that has space to hold 5 int. You can find further information on this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222531/why-int-a-new-int1-instead-of-just-int-a

Comment: The first `int` is for declaration: this variable will be an array containing primitive `int` elements. The second `int` is for instantiation: you are allocating memory to hold the `int` elements.

Comment: The first `int` is part of the specification of the type of variable `myArray`.  The second `int` is part of a Java expression that instantiates an array of `int`.  That the expression produces an object of the correct type for initialization of the variable does follow from the repeat of `int`, but that does not imply that it is redundant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so `int[] myArray = new [5]` would be wrong right? So the second **int** is like a safety mechanism for java to know that i cant be a byte, short or long value ?

Comment: @AvoKarato your proposed alternative is syntactically invalid.  The `new` operator requires a type as its operand, and `[5]` is not a type.  You can view the requirement for the type to be repeated as a safety mechanism, but I prefer to understand it by viewing the overall statement is a compound of two substantially independent pieces (variable declaration and initializer), each of which has its own rules.  Java is requiring *consistency* in how you instantiate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `int` and other primitive types, you're correct, the double declaration is largely superfluous.

But consider this example:

```
Object [] array = new String[5];
```

This is valid Java code (even though it is slightly broken*).

On a more general level it follows the same pattern as when you're initialising any variable with a new object:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

The first `Foo` is the type of the variable *(what shape the box is)*, the second is the type of the actual object *(what shape is the thing you put in the box)*.

*Note: Starting with Java 10, you can declare local variables with the keyword `var`, thus eliminating the need to specify the type twice:*

```
var array = new int[5];
```

The compiler will infer from this that the type of `array` will be the same as the object it's initialised with. (`int[]` in this case).

*It is broken because if you try to put into the array anything other than a `String`, the code only fails at runtime, not during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The construct in `int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` is handled as a special case. The compiler knows that `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` is creating an `int[]` array because of the declared type.

However, the full array creation syntax for the int array is `new int[5]` (it can vary), which tells the compiler that a new `int[]` array is created, regardless of the declared type:

For example, you can declare an `Object` variable, and assign an `int` array to it:

```
Object myArrayObject = new int[5]; //OK: this creates an int array
```

Whereas this won't work:

```
Object myArrayObject = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; //won't compile
```

Comment: And as I recall, the `int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` form wasn't always supported.  I don't remember when it was introduced, but I'm pretty sure that back in the day you had to spell out `int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` (which you still can do).

Comment: But when `int[] my Array = new` **any other type than int** `[5]` wouldnt compile, why does java want me to say **int** AGAIN?

Comment: @AvoKarato It's not just about stating `int`. Remember, you also specify the size (`new int[5]` or `new int[arraySize]` using a variable). Would you have wanted java to allow you to type `new [5]` or something like that? It doesn't make much difference and the benefit of allowing developers to omit `int` just when initializing inline would be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

So when you type new, you are specifying you want java to allocate memory to the heap. How much memory? Ah yes enough memory for 5 integers, int[5]. So java will allocated enough consecutive memory on the heap to store 5 integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
```

means you declare an array that can contain integer values called `myArray` (by `int[] myArray`) and you define it as an integer-array of size 5 afterwards (`= new int[5];`);

These steps are made inline, you could alternatively do the same in two lines:

```
int[] myArray;        // declaration
myArray = new int[5]; // definition
```

Answer (score 0):

First is the data type of the array. And other int is for the intialization of 5 integer object in the array