# Java array using stack space

Tags: java, arrays

This is the usual way for declare a Java array:

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
```

But this array is using heap space. Is there a way we can declare an array using stack space like c++?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: moar stackoverflow.

Comment: Array is a container object. All objects go on the heap.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I think is it faster to access space in stack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Array is stored in stack or heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099695/java-array-is-stored-in-stack-or-heap)

Comment: You lose a micro-second or two in creating/collecting off the heap, but, unless you are doing this skillions of times, worrying about such optimizations is futile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a word, no.

The only variables that are stored on the stack are primitives and object references.  In your example, the `arr` reference is stored on the stack, but it references data that is on the heap.

If you're asking this question coming from C++ because you want to be sure your memory is cleaned up, read about [garbage collection](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html).  In short, Java automatically takes care of cleaning up memory in the heap as well as memory on the stack.

Comment: If the JIT sees an opportunity to optimize by keeping the array in a particular place in memory, it might do that, but that's its job, not yours.

Answer (score 21):

`Arrays are objects` irrespective of whether it holds primitive type or object type, so like any other object its `allocated space on the heap.`

`But then from Java 6u23` version, `Escape Analysis` came into existence, which is by `default activated in Java 7`.

`Escape Analysis is about the scope of the object`, `when an object is defined inside a method scope rather than a class scope`, then the JVM knows that this object cant escape this limited method scope, and applies various optimization on it.. like Constant folding, etc

```
Then it can also allocate the object which is defined in the method scope,
on the Thread's Stack, which is accessing the method.
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are dynamically allocated so they go on the heap.

I mean, what happens when you do this:

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
arr = new int[5];
```

If the first allocation was done on the stack, how would we garbage collect it? The reference `arr` is stored on the stack, but the actual array of data must be on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet supported as a language feature, because that would require [value types](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) since passing on-stack data by reference would not be safe.

But as an optimization ([escape analysis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)) the JVM may already do that for local variables containing small, fixed-size arrays iff it can prove that it does not escape the local/callee scope. That said, it's just a runtime optimization and not some spec guarantee, so relying on it is difficult.