# why Java does NOT support fixed size array on stack memory?

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

In C and C++, you can use `int num[100];`, so space allocation happends on stack memory. In Java, you can NOT use `int[100] num;`, but only like `int[] number = new Integer[100]` which make allocation on heap-memory.

So, is it true that Java does NOT support fixed size array on stack? If so, why?

Comment: I don't have a reference for it, but I seem to recall that if `number` is a local and it doesn't survive the method call, it's entirely possible the JVM will optimize it onto a stack frame rather than using heap *if it's worth doing*. Remember that the JVM does the vast majority of minute Java optimization like this, rather than the programmer or compiler doing them.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953806/java-array-using-stack-space

Comment: @T.J.Crowder More specifically, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).

Comment: @biziclop: Thank you, that's the term I was trying to remember!

Comment: @biziclop: Am I reading that correctly that it *won't* use the stack for a non-escaping array? I can see that there would need to be several guards on doing so (not least size), but I'm a bit surprised to read *"It does **not** replace a heap allocation with a stack allocation for non-globally escaping objects."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, that only means objects that escape the method but not the thread (parse it as `(non-globally) escaping` rather than `non-(globally escaping)` :)). They can't be allocated on the stack for obvious reasons but any locking on them will still be optimised away.

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks! I see what you mean.