# Java: fixed size array of 2D int array

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to create an array of 2D int arrays like:

```
int n = 100;
int[][] [] a = new int[][] [n];
```

Array has a fixed length `n` and matrices (2D arrays) have different non-zero sizes (at least `1 x 1`).

For performance I would like to store that in the stack, not like:

```
ArrayList<int[][]> a = new ArrayList<int[][]>(n);
```

which will be stored on the heap as far as I know.

Comment: Arrays are *always* stored in the heap - at least notionally. They're reference types. (It's possible that very smart JVMs will perform escape analysis, but you should *assume* that it will be on the heap.)

Comment: Your arrays wouldn't be stored on the stack if they go into a collection. Java *may* try to optimize this ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2099726/335858); see Jon's note at the bottom of the answer) but it does not have to.

Comment: Suggestion, 2D array are overrated: Use a pseudo-2D-array with size of length * width, and access with `[x+(length*y)]`

Comment: Even some simple array like `int[] a = new int[5]` will be on the heap.. Alright, thanks for information, so `ArrayList` is a solution.

Comment: @ TheZ: very interesting, would be nice to see the reasons why [x*y] linear array is better than 2D array..

Comment: @SophieSperner you probably wanted `new int[n][][];`

Comment: @SophieSperner a 1D array is often chosen when an array is non-jagged and rectangular as it can in cases be more efficient, but in this case your array __is__ jagged, so ignore him.

Comment: Whoops, forgot the length and typed it wrong! Fixed. Sleepy brain is not good... for clarity: capacity of `xsize * ysize`, and access with `[x+(xsize*y)]`. Note that the technique can be expanded to any size multidimensional array as needed (it just complicates the access calculation a little more)

Comment: @SophieSperner hopefully I've answered your question! Note that `List` and `ArrayList` are __not__ meant as replacements for arrays.

Comment: @veer Often ArrayList is a better choice than using array and the performance difference is often not important.

Comment: @PeterLawrey maybe if what you want is a `List`, then sure; my point is that they're not congruent, not that there is a performance difference.

Comment: @veer its not a drop in replacement that's for sure. There is a performance difference between `int[]` and `List<Integer>` but even then it might be as much you might expect esp if the values are small. ;)

Answer (score 4):

To create a 3D array

```
int n = 100;
int[][][] a = new int[n][][];
```

This creates 100 array of array of any dimension.

This is almost as (in)efficient as

```
List<int[][]> a = new ArrayList<int[][]>(n);
```

Comment: @downvoter Can you comment as to why?

Comment: +1 as consolation for the downvote (5:1 payback--win!).

Comment: Just for humor: nothing can be "almost as (in)efficient as X" since it would have to approach the efficiency of X from both sides at once :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true, the difference doesn't matter either way. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create an array of 2D int arrays like:
>
> ```
> int n = 100;
> int[][] [] a = new int[][] [n];
> ```

--> this is invalid with syntax, you will get compiler error. Use :

```
int n = 100;
int[][] [] a = new int[n][] [];
```

but `a` is an object as arrays in java are object so `a` will be stored on heap not on stack.