# What part of an array local variable is stored on the stack? And which part is on the heap?

Tags: java, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

Suppose we have the following code:

```
void method() {
    int[] test = new int[3];
    test[0] = 0;
    test[1] = 1;
    test[2] = 2;
}
```

From what I read from [Jon Skeet's post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099726/4075551), the `new int[3]` part is equivalent to:

```
public class ArrayInt3 {
    public readonly int length = 3;
    public int value0;
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
}
```

So does that mean `test` (a reference to `ArrayInt3`) is on the stack? And does that mean `ArrayInt3` is on the heap? And I suppose `value0`, `value1`, and `value2` are on the heap as well (i.e. 0, 1, 2 in this example)?

So in total, there is 4 objects on the heap, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no object on the stack. On the stack, there will be a reference value to the single `int[]` object stored in the heap.

You have to start making the distinction between objects, variables, and values.

Local variables are part of the method stackframe, which is on the stack. So the reference value to the `int[]` will be stored in the variable, on the stack.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy Those are not objects. First, `ArrayInt3` is a type. The rest are values. They are part of the single `int[]` object. They are not independent.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy If they were initialized, they would be 4 reference values pointing to 4 other objects on the heap.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy No, there is a single object on the heap, the `int[]` object.

Comment: Assuming value0, value1, and value2 are initialized, then what do we have on the heap exactly? value0, value1, value2, and ArrayInt3, right? I apologize for asking this poorly.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy You'll have memory allocated for an instance of type `ArrayInt3`. That memory will be large enough to fit exactly those fields and their value.

Comment: Okay this is a poor example but if we assume instead of ints, they were objects like House objects, it would be 3 House objects on the heap + ArrayInt3 object on the heap?

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy Yes, the `ArrayInt3` object would have enough memory allocated for 3 reference values, each referencing a `House` object, all on the heap.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the confusion.